# On Windows can I change the mouse cursor icon when I'm pressing the left mouse button?

Tags: windows, mouse, cursor

You might have noticed on some video games that the cursor changes when the left or right mouse buttons are being pressed. Can I do this on regular windows? I know that in Control panel -> Mouse -> Pointers you can change the mouse cursors, but there's no option for "Pressed Select" or something similar. If anybody has a few pointers kindly let us know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using a third party tool, you can change the pointer icon *in medias res*. The  free application [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) can take a variety of actions based on mouse button and wheel action, including changing the mouse cursor on [p. 11 of the manual](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/X-Mouse%20Button%20Control%20User%20Guide.pdf).

That said, *X-Mouse Button Control* has **many** options, and it might take some time to set this up according to your needs, but this should at least point you in the right direction. Don't say, "Cursors, foiled again!"